# what method is called after view is rotated

Tags: ipad, uiview, uipopover

I want to change position of UIPopover after the view is rotated. can you tell me what method is called after view is rotated so that I can get the coordinates of UI elments in the final view rendered after rotation of view

popover behavior in any Apples native application. You'll see that in response to device rotation popover should disappear before rotation animation and appear again on new appropriate place after it ends. So you should dismiss your popover and then popup it on new place with new coordinates (how to get these coordinates)

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `-[UIViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:]`:

> Sent to the view controller after the user interface rotates. … Subclasses may override this method to perform additional actions immediately after the rotation. … By the time this method is called, the `interfaceOrientation` property is already set to the new orientation.

Comment: Hi Ole, thnks you got read this hey what I am trying to do this suppose I tapped on a textfiled popover appeared then due to flexible width of view that field moved on view rotation I want the fresh coordinated of textfield so that I can redraw the popover